# how unique is WebGL fingerprint

Tags: browser, webgl, fingerprint

Recently I am researching some unique Id for browser and i came across https://panopticlick.eff.org/
realize there is a "Hash of WebGL fingerprint" but I don't know what is the key will affect the value
I have tested using 2 difference resolution screen (same PC) to run and update my browser minor version and it return me the same value for the key.

Does anyone can help me to understand how the Hash of WebGL fingerprint generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone can help me to understand how the Hash of WebGL fingerprint generated?

The WebGl fingerprint hash is generated by rendering a pattern (or <strike>low</strike> high entropy image (Image that does not compress well)) and then creating a hash from the resulting rendered pixels.

That image is rendered to a frame buffer with a fixed size so changing screen resolution will not effect the resulting hash.

The vertex and (particularly the) fragment shaders will be written such as to exaggerate known GPU processing differences. What these are will depend on the finger printer's code.

As WebGL does not allow pre compiled shaders thus with a little effort you can gain access to the shaders source code by stepping through the code until you find the webGL context `shaderSource` call. The hash is generated by JavaScript, and again will depend on the finger printer's preferred method.

Answer (score 3):

The hash for WebGL is usually specific to a GPU so an NVidia 2080 GTX will have a different fingerprint than an Nvidia GeForce GT 750M or an Intel Iris Pro etc... Changing the screen resolution will not affect the WebGL fingerprint but it will effect your fingerprint in some other part of panopticlick

It's generated well you can [look at the code](https://github.com/EFForg/panopticlick) but in general you query all the features of WebGL ([like these](https://webglreport.com/)). They'll be somewhat different by GPU.

You then render a few things like a small texture, a colored quad, and maybe a line over a few pixels. Different GPUs have slightly different algorithms or math on how they interpolate colors so based on the results you get a few more bits of data to add the to fingerprint.

panpoticlick exaggerates though. For example I have an iPhone 11. Panopticlick's fingerprint claims my phone is unique to 200k. The only things unique about an iphone 11 is the time zone and language settings, otherwise all iPhones 11s have the exact same fingerprint.

I'm in the Pacific Standard Time Zone. There are at least 55 million people in the Pacific Standard Time Zone. To be unique to 1 in 200k would mean there are a total of 275 iPhone 11s in all of California, Oregon, and Washington State combine set to English. We know that's false. There are 10s of thousands of iPhone 11s in those 3 states, maybe 100s of thousands.

The point is, panopticlick doesn't really get enough traffic to know if a fingerprint means anything and since no one visits every fingerprint appears to look unique.

Comment: Though if it was only an hardware matter, surely using two different browsers on the same machine would generate the same hash. But it doesn't. Even Chrome stable vs Canary produce different results.